# Nested array assign new value

Tags: php

how to I assign new value to the itemprices when item is equal to 5.

```
Object (
    [name] => xxxxx
    [phone] => xxxxxx
    [email] => xxxxxxx
    [items] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 ) 
    [itemprices] => Array ( [0] => 1.00 [4] => 1.00 [5] => 1.00 )
    [itemqtys] => Array ( [0] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 )
}
```

Comment: its a object or associative array??

Comment: Could we get a little deeper explenation with examples (like before and after arrays) ? I don't really understand where you want to assign new value in which cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

here $array is parent array(Object)

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
   if($key == "itemprices"){
    // Get inner Array
    $in_arr = $array[$key];
    // Now you can Assign new value
    $newValue = 10;
    $in_arr[5] = $newValue;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use associative arrays?
Like:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name = 'xxxxx';
$obj->email = 'xxxxx';
$obj->phone = 'xxxxx';
$obj->items = array(
    array( 'quantities' => 1,
           'price' => 1.00, ),
    array( 'quantities' => 1,
           'price' => 1.00, ),
    array( 'quantities' => 1,
           'price' => 1.00, )
);
```

Just an idea to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You already assigned a key value 5 in the itemprices inner array to store the price when items numbers equals to 5. In that case, just findout the array & use items number as your key :p

```
$newprice=1.50;
$arr['itemprices'][5]=$newprice; //$arr['itemprices'] is the array you want to access, and also another array, & the item inside it you want to access have the key as 5 (items number) :p
```